# call new master from detail in splitview

Tags: ios, objective-c

hy,

i have a normal spitviewapplication with 1 master and 1 detail, to communicate between both i set this code in appDelegate:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
ImageGaleryViewController *rightViewController = (ImageGaleryViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
CatalogPopUpViewController *controller = (CatalogPopUpViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
controller.delegate = rightViewController;
```

now i want to make a second master and be able to switch between them in the detail, like having two buttons and click one opens 1s master other button opens 2nd master, but want to be abble to comunicate from the master to the detail too, setting a delegate, i can make a new viewcontroller and make a segue to replace with master, but how can i set the delegate? to comunicate from the masters to the detail? i hope i made my problem understadable.

Answer (score 0):

i got it , i used

> [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"catalogMasterSegue" sender:self];

to call the master with, the segue then in prepare for segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"catalogMasterSegue"])
    {
        CatalogPopUpViewController *controller=[[[segue destinationViewController]viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
        controller.delegate=self;
    }
}
```